# Number of ways to arrange 3 x's 3 y's, and 10 z's

Tags: combinatorics

Number of ways to arrange 3 x's  3 y's, and 10 z's so that each x and each y is between 2 z's on both its sides.

This is what I did:

z__z__z__z__z__z__z|zzz

The 3 x's and 3 y's can go to any of the 6 places denoted by __ and so the number of arrangements is $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$. And the block on the left, when seen as one entity, can be arranged in $4!/3!$ ways so the total number of is $\frac{6!}{3!3!} \times 4 = 80$ ways.

Is this the correct approach? Any other interesting ways to do this?

Comment: The general idea is good, dtail is not quite right. Line up **all** the z's, so there are $9$ gaps. We need to choose $3$ for the x's, and then take care of the y's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the possibility of the $x$'s and $y$'s appearing in the last two slots at the end. There are $9$ slots. We need to choose $6$ of them. We then permute the $x$'s and $y$'s using the multinomial distribution:

$$\binom{9}{6} \cdot \frac{6!}{3! 3!}$$

Answer (score 3):

I would reformulate the problem as permuting 3 groups of `zx`, 3 groups of `zy`, and 3 loose `z`, and then put the final `z` at the end of the string statically. That gives $\binom{9}{3\;3\;3}=1680$ ways.